# Getting words by words of a string keeping the spacing between each words

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_string= 'EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD INTELLIGENCE..GET VALUABLE INSIGHTS…'
```

Expected output:.

```
EXPLORE
EXPLORE  DATA..
EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD
```

I have tried with  `re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  my_string).split()`

which gives:  `['EXPLORE', 'DATA', 'ADD', 'INTELLIGENCE', 'GET', 'VALUABLE', 'INSIGHTS']`

While taking first two string it will be `EXPLORE DATA` which does not keep the actual spacing in the `my_string`. Expected is `EXPLORE  DATA..`.  How to get the expected output. Like first word, then first two words, then first 3 words..and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the index of those word list that you have created

```
import re

my_string = 'EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD INTELLIGENCE..GET VALUABLE INSIGHTS…'
word_list = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  my_string).split()
for word in word_list:
    end_index = my_string.find(word) + len(word) // get the index at the end of the word
    print(my_string[:end_index])
```

This results in

```
EXPLORE                                                                                                              
EXPLORE  DATA                                                                                                        
EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD                                                                                                  
EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD INTELLIGENCE                                                                                     
EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD INTELLIGENCE..GET                                                                                
EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD INTELLIGENCE..GET VALUABLE                                                                       
EXPLORE  DATA.. ADD INTELLIGENCE..GET VALUABLE INSIGHTS
```